# Why doesn't my navigation drawer work in my fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer in a fragment, but my app keeps crashing. The navigation drawer itself works fine without a drawer toggle. The problem is that when I try to add the code to create a drawer toggle, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong?

TestListFragment:

```
public class TestListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView testRecycler;
    private String[] names;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_list, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_open_drawer, R.string.nav_close_drawer);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        testRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.test_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        testRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        names = new String[Test.testData.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i] = Test.testData[i].getTitle();
        }

        TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(names);
        testRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_test_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/test_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

menu_nav:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/category1"
        android:title="@string/category_1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/category2"
        android:title="@string/category_2" />
</menu>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: According to the logcat, the error is an IllegalStateException. It's saying that "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."